# How to vlookup from another workbook selected through browser using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to use vlookup to get the data from a c1:c4,4 of the selected excel file by using vba. I want to get the data from the GL worksheet of selected workbook. Vlookup will first look for the value in the left of the active cell.

Here is the solution I tried to make but it is not working. There is a problem with when referencing the file selected by browser in the formula.

I would be appreciated your help.

Thank you

```
Sub bdmachine()

Dim filetoopen As Variant

Dim openbook As Workbook


filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for the Breakdown that you want to turn into a lead sheet.", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")

If filetoopen <> False Then

With Selection
   
Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoopen)

.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], openbook.sheets(GL)!C1:C4,4,0)"
       

   

End With



End If




End Sub
```

Comment: First: Your variable `openbook` is a workbook object - you can't use it within a string. Second. Build the formula manually and see how it is referencing the opened workbook. Then you should be able to fix the formula.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I tried to record macro but the macro written is shows the name of the workbook instead of openned workbook

Comment: Try `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], " & openbook.Sheets("GL").Name() & "!C1:C4,4,0)"`.

Comment: Hello, now it works thanks a  lot but now it asks for selecting the excel file twice. I mean browser screen appears twice.

Comment: And I dont want to change the name of the opened file as GL. What I want is to making a vlookup formula which can be seen as what it had been done manually. I mean the person after looking at it should be able to see the original name of the opened workbook that is the source of vlookup.

Comment: After applying this, the cell showing VLOOKUP(B4, [GL]GL!$A:$B,2,0). Instead of the first [GL], how can we put the original name of opened file via browser?